# Zend_View and addHelperPath

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

I've got a problem using an empty Zend_View and addHelperPath.
Someone knows where is the difference between

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->addHelperPath(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/layouts', 
   'FOO_View_Helper'
);
```

and

```
$view = new Zend_View;
$view->addHelperPath(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/layouts', 
    'FOO_View_Helper'
);
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setView($view);
$helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$helper->setView($view);
```

With example number one, my view helper got loaded. Example number two said

```
Plugin by name 'PriceOutput' was not found in the registry; used paths:
    Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;./views\helpers/
```

I've added an

```
echo "<xmp>", var_dump($registry), "</xmp>";
```

in

```
PluginLoader::load($name, $throwExceptions = true)
```

and the helperPaths are all at the same place. But with example Number two, ZF seems to search only in `Zend_View_Helper` and not in `FOO_View_Helper`.

Any ideas?

Like I told, the first example took a look at FOO_View_Helper, the 2nd not:
`Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'FooBar' was not found in the registry; used paths: FOO_View_Helper_: C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/basket/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/globallayer/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/globallayer/help/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/globallayer/styleinfolayer/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/layout/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/nys/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/overview/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/search/;C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_webshop\application/views/helpers/singleproductview/;C:\Programme\Zend in C:\Programme\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\trunk_core_webshop\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php  on line 414`

($view->getHelperPaths() should be better :P )

Comment: Try calling a non-existant helper in your view script, the error output should tell you which helper paths it is attempting to access.

Answer (score 2):

With this one

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->addHelperPath(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/helpers/layouts', 
   'FOO_View_Helper'
);
```

You are getting the existing View and setting the path, this is correct.

But with the second example you are creating a new view and then setting the path, thus replacing the existing View that was automatically (and correctly) loaded by your Bootstrap. This new View has no idea about your Bootstrap and therefore no idea about your autoloader - hence the errors.

Comment: Any idea, what configurations I'd to set manually? getView() retrieves ViewRenderer::initView() with the pre-configured View instance. I've tried to "copy" the object structure as good as possible and especially print_r() said that they should be the same objects. (Sure not, but all dumps and object-structure are the same). The View is set in _initView() in my bootstrap class